# MarkerClusterer

Tags: javascript

I am trying to use MarkerClusterer to cluster together my points on a Google map. For some reason the map works but just shows individual markers and does not cluster them and I cannot figure out why. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You have a script tag in the middle of your javascript file `<script src="https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/
    javascript/examples/markerclusterer/markerclusterer.js"></script>`, that is incorrect.

Comment: What does `http://localhost/innotech/inc/get_data_google_api.php` return?  Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates your issue.

Comment: @geocodezip    http://localhost/innotech/inc/get_data_google_api.php  , it gave me the data from my data base , the information who taken by the map and display the markers , contain (longitude + latitude +Route+secteur+..... )

Comment: Edit your question and remove the error already mentioned above. Provide a sample of the returned JSON or even better, include that somehow in your code so that it can be tested. In other words, provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) as requested. Only describing the problem is too vague.